# Intuition behind unit hypersphere/n-ball volume

Tags: geometry, intuition, dimension-theory-analysis

Obviously the volume of a unit hypercube is always $1$.

I know that the volume of a unit hypersphere is given by:
$$
\dfrac{\pi^\frac{d}{2}}{\Gamma\Big(\dfrac{d}{2} + 1\Big)}
$$
which [rises sharply until about $d=5$, then falls off a cliff](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=graph+pi%5E(d%2F2)%2FGamma(d%2F2+%2B+1)+for+d+from+0+to+50).

Why should it be this way? I can't get my head around why volume should increase with dimension only to a point.

Comment: Tag edits or suggestions very much appreciated.

Comment: It is more meaningful to [look at](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=graph+pi%5E(d%2F2)%2FGamma(d%2F2+%2B+1)*(1%2F2)%5Ed+for+d+from+1+to+10) the volume of the hypersphere *inscribed* in the unit hypercube.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question has a thorough answer [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/8258/whats-a-nice-argument-that-shows-the-volume-of-the-unit-ball-in-mathbb-rn-a)

For your convenience, Let me quote top answers. ( I advise you to read the full discussion on MathOverflow).

> The ultimate reason is, of course, that the typical coordinate of a point in the unit ball is of size $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\ll 1$. This can be turned into a simple geometric argument (as suggested by fedja) using the fact that an $n$-element set has $2^n$ subsets:
> At least $n/2$ of the coordinates of a point in the unit ball are at most $\sqrt{\frac{2}{n}}$ in absolute value, and the rest are at most $1$ in absolute value. Thus, the unit ball can be covered by at most $2^n$ bricks (right-angled parallelepipeds) of volume $$\left(2\sqrt{\frac{2}{n}}\right)^{n/2},$$ each corresponding to a subset for the small coordinates. Hence, the volume of the unit ball is at most $$2^n \cdot \left(2\sqrt{\frac{2}{n}}\right)^{n/2} = \left(\frac{128}{n}\right)^{n/4}\rightarrow0.$$ In fact, the argument shows that the volume of the unit ball decreases faster than any exponential, so the volume of the ball of any fixed radius also goes to $0$.

Another one says,

> The reason is because the length of the diagonal cube goes to infinity.
>
> The cube in some sense does exactly what we expect.  If it's side lengths are $1$, it will have the same volume in any dimension.  So lets take a cube centered at the origin with side lengths $r$.  Then what is the smallest sphere which contains this cube?  It would need to have radius $r\sqrt{d}$, so that radius of the sphere required goes to infinity.
>
> Perhaps this gives some intuition.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for that, the second quote in particular was exactly what I needed. :)